# Why doesn't wp_oembed_get() for the video post format not work?

Tags: post-meta, oembed

I have this code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_format ('video') ) { ?>
    <div class="video-head">
        <?php
        $video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_format_video_embed', true );
        if ( wp_oembed_get( $video) ) {
            echo wp_oembed_get($video);
        } else {
            echo $video;
        } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And it should output, on the posts-list, say, homepage, the iframe of the video embedded in my post, like this:

[image]

For some reason, it doesn't.

The `get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_format_video_embed', true );` fails and returns nothing.

The biggest issue is **that WordPress sees the video as part of the content itself, rather than it having the video on a "higher up level" as "image" is for the "Image Post Type"**, it's left as nothing more than content, so, of course my query wouldn't pick it up.

What am I to do here?

Comment: What happens if you replace `$post->ID` with `get_the_ID()`. Note that `wp_oembed_get()` doesn't cache, last time I checked. Not sure if 4.9 changed that?

Comment: @birgire Still nothing.

Comment: Then try to replace it with the actual post ID to test, e.g. 1234.

Comment: What's the content of the `_format_video_embed` meta field? `get_post_meta()` will only return nothing if it's empty. Where did you save the video?